# Sorting a List of Objects based on another short list python

Tags: python

I am sorting a list of services based on a sorted list of favorite types of services

I have sortingServices function that should take a list of services and a list of favorite types(from user object) , and it should return a list of sorted objects of services .

```
class User :
    def __init__(self, id, rates):
        self.id = id
        self.rates = rates



user1 = User(123 , ["Education" , "food" , "shopping","A"])   

class Service :
    def __init__(self,id,body,type,fees):
        self.id = id
        self.body= body
        self.type=type 
        self.fee = fees


service1 = Service(123,"gh","food",12)
service2 = Service(123,"gh","Education",12)
service3 = Service(123,"gh","shopping",12)
service4 = Service(123,"gh","Education",12)
service5 = Service(123,"gh","Education",12)
service6 = Service(123,"gh","shopping",12)
service7 = Service(123,"gh","A",12)

Services= [service1,service2,service3,service3 ,service4,service5,service6,service7]


def sortingServices (services ,user):

   sorted(long_list, key=lambda e: (short_list.index(e),e) if e in short_list  else (len(short_list),e))

sortingServices(Services , user1)
```

the output should be :

```
Services = [service2 , service4 ,service5 , service1 , service3 , service6 , service7 ]
```

Comment: Where is `long_list` and `short_list` defined?

Comment: long_list =[service1,service2,service3,service3 ,service4,service5,service6,service7]

Comment: short_list = ["Education" , "food" , "shopping","A"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `Service.type` is in `User.rates` and use that index.

**Ex:**

```
Class User :
    def __init__(self, id, rates):
        self.id = id
        self.rates = rates      

user1 = User(123 , ["Education" , "food" , "shopping","A"])   

class Service :
    def __init__(self,id,body,type,fees):
        self.id = id
        self.body= body
        self.type=type 
        self.fee = fees    

service1 = Service(1,"gh","food",12)
service2 = Service(2,"gh","Education",12)
service3 = Service(3,"gh","shopping",12)
service4 = Service(4,"gh","Education",12)
service5 = Service(5,"gh","Education",12)
service6 = Service(6,"gh","shopping",12)
service7 = Service(7,"gh","A",12)

Services= [service1,service2,service3,service4,service5,service6,service7]

def sortingServices (long_list ,short_list):
    return sorted(long_list, key=lambda e: short_list.index(e.type) if e.type in short_list else len(short_list))

for i in sortingServices(Services , user1.rates):
    print(i.id)
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
5
1
3
6
7
```

Comment: Thank you so mush .